# Convert switch statment from C#

Tags: vb.net

How may i convert such `C#`'s two statments correctly to `VB.NET`?:

```
public decimal Round(decimal value)
{
    if (value < 300)
        return value;

    if (((long)value % 10) is not 5 and not 9)
        return value;

    return (long)value + (((long)value / 10) % 10) switch
    {
        0 => -10,
        1 => -20,
        2 or 7 => 20,
        3 or 8 => 10,
        5 => 40,
        6 => 30,
        _ => 0,
    };
}
```

I am stuck on `is not` `and not` part:

```
Public Function Round(ByVal value As Decimal) As Decimal
            If value < 300 Then
                Return value
            End If

            If (TypeOf (CType(value Mod 10, Long)) Is Not 5 And  Is Not CType(9, Integer)) Then
                Return value
            End If

            Return CType(value, Long) + ((CType(value / 10, Long)) Mod 10) switch
    {
        0 => -10,
        1 => -20,
        2 Or 7 => 20,
        3 Or 8 => 10,
        5 => 40,
        6 => 30,
        _ => 0,
    }

End Function
```

On the `If(TypeOf ... )` line Visual Studio gives me this error in red squibles under the `Is Not 5` and `Is Not 9` expressions:

> Expression Expected

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? The first one reads like an English sentence so I find it hard to believe that you couldn't convert that with just a little thought. As for the second one, have you read the documentation for the switch expression to see how it works? This site is not a code conversion service so you have to have tried for yourself first.

Comment: What is the actual declared data type of `value`?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn value is decimal

Comment: @jmcilhinney u right, i forgot to add my tries. Please check main post again.

Comment: C# pattern matching's `is not` is known as `<>` in VB.

Comment: @GSerg tried but still something is wrong

Comment: @Arie That's because there is no pattern matching in VB.

Comment: Note that while VB doesn't have switch expressions, you could emulate it with an inline lambda function containing a `Select Case` (though I think it would be of debatable benefit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VB.Net equivalent of `switch` is `Select`. Don't let the new pattern matching fool you: it lets you write the expression inline, but it still boils down to a `Select Case` expression.

I also re-wrote some things a bit to reduce casting.

```vb
Public Function Round(value As Decimal) As Decimal
    If value < 300 Then Return value

    Dim l As Long = CLng(value)
    Dim r As Integer = l Mod 10

    If r <> 5 AndAlso r <> 9 Then Return value

    r = (l \ 10) Mod 10

    Select Case r
        Case 0
            Return CDec(-10 + l)
        Case 1
            Return CDec(-20 + l)
        Case 2, 7
            Return CDec(20 + l)
        Case 3, 8
            Return CDec(10 + l)
        Case 5
            Return CDec(40 + l)
        Case 6
            Return CDec(30 + l)
        Case Else
            Return CDec(l)
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: many thanks ! U sure that this is generally correct right? P.S Is this `CLng` casting really required ? : `Dim l As Long = CLng(value)`. Asking because my resharper notifies that it's redundant :O

Comment: @Arie It's required if you're using Object Strict, which you absolutely should be doing.

Comment: ^ `Option Strict` that is.

Comment: Arg, yes, "Option Strict". Sigh. It seems my fingers and my brain aren't on speaking terms today.